# Align masked Rectangle in a ZStack while also changing masked area [SwiftUI]

Tags: swiftui

For a rating display I am trying to split an Image up into two parts, a black and a red one and I would like the red part to take up a specific percentage of the whole image. The problem I am having is that the Rectangle is aligned to the centre of the other image and when changing the alignment of the ZStack to `.leading`, the Rectangle does move but unfortunately the masked area of the image does not change.

```swift
ZStack {
    Image("Car")
            
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(ColorManager.brand)
        .frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
        .mask(Image("Car"))
}
```

[Without alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW5OA.png)

```swift
ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .center)) {
    Image("Car")
            
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(ColorManager.brand)
        .frame(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
        .mask(Image("Car"))
}
```

[With alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwtE2.png)

How could I change the alignment of the Rectangle to `.leading`, while also masking the leading part of the image?

edit: [Desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C55Ig.jpg)

Comment: i couldn't udnerstand the question what are you trying to achive exactly?

Comment: I have added another image to show the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just make clipping at needed location. Here is a complete demo of possible approach (on custom CarView as I don't have car image like your).

Prepared with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct CarView: View {
    var body: some View {
         Image(systemName: "car").resizable()
            .frame(width: 200, height: 80)
    }
}

struct MaskShape: Shape {
    var alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        switch alignment {
            case .leading:
                return Rectangle().path(in: rect.divided(atDistance: rect.width / 3, from: .minXEdge).slice)
            case .center:
                return Rectangle().path(in: rect.insetBy(dx: rect.width / 3, dy: 0))
            case .trailing:
                return Rectangle().path(in: rect.divided(atDistance: rect.width / 3, from: .maxXEdge).slice)
            default:
                return Rectangle().path(in: rect)
        }
    }
}

struct TestCarMaskView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CarView()
                .overlay(
                     Rectangle()
                          .foregroundColor(.red)
                          .mask(CarView())
                          .clipShape(MaskShape())
            )
            CarView()
                .overlay(
                     Rectangle()
                          .foregroundColor(.red)
                          .mask(CarView())
                          .clipShape(MaskShape(alignment: .leading))
            )
            CarView()
                .overlay(
                     Rectangle()
                          .foregroundColor(.red)
                          .mask(CarView())
                          .clipShape(MaskShape(alignment: .trailing))
            )
        }
    }
}
```

so your code could look like (of course sizes of mask you can tune for your needs)

```
Image("Car")
    .overlay(
         Rectangle()
             .foregroundColor(ColorManager.brand)
             .mask(Image("Car"))
             .clipShape(MaskShape(alignment: .leading))
    )
```